# How to get a executed step information in a running job in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jobs

We want to log the job history into a table named `JobHistory`. And the solution of us maybe as follows.

Set three steps in the job.

Step one call the sp which will write the start time, job name, job id and other job information into `JobHistory`.

Step two call the sp which do the actual works.

Step three call the sp which get the executing information of step two, such as duration, error message, executing output, and update the end time of `JobHistory`.

Is this solution works? If it works, how can we get the executing information of step two in step three?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good to me.

In SQL-Server 2008+ you can get information about Duration, LastExecutionTime, Logical reads and wrights using system view  [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)

```
select eps.object_id, eps.last_execution_time, eps.execution_count, eps.last_worker_time/1000 as CPU,
    eps.last_logical_writes as [Writes],
    eps.last_logical_reads+eps.last_logical_writes as [AggIO]   
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats eps
where eps.object_id=object_id(N'Your_procedure_name')
```

As for error, in SQL-Server 2005+ you can get it using function [ERROR_MESSAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRY
    exec YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```